# Use aggregation for update in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Is there a way to use [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) in Spring Data MongoDB **update** query?

Suppose, I want to set `firstName` value into `fullName` field for users without `lastName`. Native query looks like this:

```js
db.getCollection("users").update({lastName: ""}, [{ $set: { "fullName" : "$firstName" } }])
```

Is it doable using Spring Data?

Answer (score 0):

`AggregationUpdate` will be part of [Spring Data MongoDB 3.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Neumann).

```java
AggregationUpdate update = AggregationUpdate.update()
    .set("average").toValue(ArithmeticOperators.valueOf("tests").avg())
    .set("grade").toValue(
        ConditionalOperators.switchCases(
            CaseOperator.when(Gte.valueOf("average").greaterThanEqualToValue(90)).then("A"),
            CaseOperator.when(Gte.valueOf("average").greaterThanEqualToValue(80)).then("B"),
            CaseOperator.when(Gte.valueOf("average").greaterThanEqualToValue(70)).then("C"),
            CaseOperator.when(Gte.valueOf("average").greaterThanEqualToValue(60)).then("D"))
        .defaultTo("F"));
```